# Gsub on a list according to pattern occurence in R

Tags: r, list, gsub

Hello everyone I have a list such as :

```
my_list<-c("YP_0092.1_CP","C_scaffold_1017_18403-23022_-__Homo_sapiens","F_scaffold_1710_2458-7549_+__Pan_troglodys","ACPDHDDHH.2","X_scaffold_3287_5022-8483_-__Neandertalensis")
```

and I would like to change `"__"` to `"_"` for each element on the list when it begins with a `X` or `F`

I should then get a new list :

```
c("YP_0092.1_CP","C_scaffold_1017_18403-23022_-__Homo_sapiens","F_scaffold_1710_2458-7549_+_Pan_troglodys","ACPDHDDHH.2","X_scaffold_3287_5022-8483_-_Neandertalensis")
```

does someone have an idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure!

```r
i <- grepl( "^(XF)", my_list )
my_list[i] <- gsub( "__", "_", my_list[i] )
```